# Google Sheet Calculation Only Updates on Return

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am using the formula below. It will only update when I go into the cell and push "enter" to leave the cell.

I think it is due to the `iferror` function. It is calculating correcting but I have to hit return.

```
=sum(iferror(January!B4,0), iferror(February!B4,0), iferror(March!B4,0), iferror(April!B4,0), iferror(May!B4,0), iferror(June!B4,0), iferror(July!B4,0), iferror(August!B4,0), iferror(September!B4,0), iferror(October!B4,0), iferror(November!B4,0), iferror(December!B4,0))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: I can't share the specific one. I created a test sheet but the issue is not showing up. weird. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LkBU5r7sjX93eWmGeu7pL8ITADuiZSsIXrNDFTHNdDs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i just removed the formula then added it back in and now it seems to be working.

Comment: could have been som glitch, ...glad it's resolved

Comment: i had the issue in multiple documents in multiple fileds

Comment: thank you for checking in.

Answer (score 1):

- no need for zeros:

  ```
  =SUM(IFERROR(January!B4), 
       IFERROR(February!B4), 
       IFERROR(March!B4), 
       IFERROR(April!B4), 
       IFERROR(May!B4),
       IFERROR(June!B4),
       IFERROR(July!B4), 
       IFERROR(August!B4),
       IFERROR(September!B4),
       IFERROR(October!B4),
       IFERROR(November!B4),
       IFERROR(December!B4))
  ```